# [Mininet/Miniedit]: Can't get the host machines connected via a router to ping each other

Tags: routing, networking, sdn, mininet

As a part of an experiment, my network has the following topology for two host machines connected to a router in mininet(on Ubuntu 22.04.02 Virtual Machine)

```
     h1 - r1 - h2
```

The host Machine 'h1' has the following configuration:
[h1 ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2Dn4.png)

The host Machine 'h2' has the following config:
[h2 ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlKCb.png)

The router r1 has the following config:
[r1 ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaYDF.png)

I am trying to setup the experimental topology such that both the hosts can access each other, which of course, is possible through configuring routing tables

I have taken the following steps:

On the **router terminal(xterm):**

```
    ifconfig r1-eth0 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.0.0.0  
    ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev r1-eth0   
    ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev r1-eth0
```

On the **h1 terminal (xterm)**

```
    ifconfig h1-eth0 192.168.0.103 netmask 255.0.0.0
    ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.3.0
    route add default gw 192.168.3.0
```

On the **h2 terminal (xterm)**

```
    ifconfig h2-eth0 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.0.0.0
    ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.3.0
    route add default gw 192.168.3.0
```

The updated routing tables for h1, h2 and r1 are as follows:

[h1 IP routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rzl3.png)
[h2 IP routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xdqa.png)
[r1 IP routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4shL1.png)

When I try pinging h2 from h1 and vice versa I get destination host unreachable error.

where am I going wrong? Is there a step I have skipped? Any insight/help is appreciated.

P.S.: I would appreciate any good resources on static IP routing.

Comment: Please never post text as screenshots. Instead, post text as text using the editor's `{}` preformat function.

Comment: I tried doing that. But for some reason, xterm wouldn't let me copy text. Hence the screenshots.Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Please don't change the question totally around after it's been answered.

Comment: Apologies.Made a blunder.I have reverted back to the original.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts/servers/VMs are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For routing to work, h1 and h2 need to be on separate subnets.

```
ifconfig h1-eth0 192.168.0.103 netmask 255.0.0.0
```

and

```
ifconfig h2-eth0 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.0.0.0
```

are on the same 192.0.0.0/8 subnet. Both try to ARP each other, failing due to lack of a common broadcast domain. Increase netmask to 255.255.255.0 = /24.

Also, the router needs to have two interfaces - one for facing and sharing a subnet with each host. The hosts need to use their respective router interface as default gateway. Generally, you can't have a (default) gateway that is outside of a host's subnet.

Comment: I have started again from scratch following your instructions:

router terminal(xterm):
`ifconfig r1-eth0 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0` <br/>
 `ifconfig r1-eth1 192.168.3.1 netmask 255.255.255.0` <br/>
 `ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev r1-eth0` <br/>  
` Ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev r1-eth1` <br/>

After setting up the configuration for h1(same IP different netmask), I failed to add an IP route via r1-eth0's inet. I get a `SIOCART: Network is unreachable` error.

Comment: You need *different* subnets on the router interfaces, each matching the attached host's. Please get your subnetting right first: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers

Comment: I did it @Zac67, the solution worked. Thank you so very much!

Comment: Hi. My problem has a slight addition to it now.Should I create a new post altogether or should I carry on here?